# TypeScript: "filter" and "find" are not returning the expected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have the following lines of code inside the `useEffect` hook which doesn't return the result I expect:

```
useEffect(() => {

console.log('===========================');
console.log('chatState.customers');
console.log(chatState.customers);
console.log(chatState.customers?.length);

if (chatState !== undefined && chatState.customers && chatState.customers.length > 0) {
  const name = 'Yoges Gamuda';

  const result = chatState.customers.filter((obj) => {
    return obj.name === name;
  });

  console.log(`result for name ${name} is: `);
  console.log(result);

  const p = chatState.customers.find((x) => x.name === name);

  if (p !== undefined) {
    console.log(`p >> id: ${p.id} name: ${p?.name}`);
  } else {
    console.log('p is undefined!');
  }

  console.log('===========================');
}
}, [chatState]);
```

Result:

[image]

I note from the above that:

- `chatState.customers` does contain data
- `chatState.customers` is of type `array` with length `39`
- the key I'm looking for ("`Yoges Gamuda`") does exist in `chatState.customers`

**Background details:**

- `chatState` comes from the `Context`:

  ```
  const { state: chatState } = chatContext;
  ```
- which is defined as below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly? I've been at it for a day now and I still am not able to figure it out.

**Edited to add**

I tried to print the values of `chatState.customers` and following is the result:

```
chatState.customers.forEach((x) => console.log(x));
```

[image]

Comment: You should use `x.name === name` instead of `x.name === chatName`.

Comment: @Nishant thanks for the catch, it's a typo but the result is still `undefined` even after correcting it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Did you try to copy `Yoges Gamuda` from `chatState.customers[0].name` in console and paste it to `const name = 'Yoges Gamuda';` just to avoid some mistakes about encodings?